# XML parsing yahoo weather forecast

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, weather

I am making an app for iphone where i want to display the current temperature and the weather image from the following xml:
    http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/UKXX0085_c.xml

I am able to do the parsing for xml and read the description tab data. But how can i further parse it to fetch temperature and weather image from it ?

Answer (score 0):

The temperature is in `yweather:condition`. Look at the `NSDictionary` returned as `attributes` of `didStartElement`.

The units of measure for the temperature is in `yweather:units` (again in the `attributes` dictionary).

The image link is included in the `description`. You should really use a HTML parser, like discussed in [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios), or (gasp) you could do use regex:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSString *imageUrlString = nil;
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:htmlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])];
if (match)
    imageUrlString = [htmlString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
```